# How to create an NSInvocation from a called method implementation?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c-runtime

I have a function that looks like this:

```
void myMethodImpl(id self, SEL _cmd, ...)
```

I use this as a implementation for a method on a class

```
class_addMethod(aClass, aSelector, (IMP)myMethodImpl, types);
```

so `myMethodImpl` get's called when a message is sent to aClass with selector aSelector. Now there I'd like to create an NSInvocation with all parameters from `myMethodImpl`.

Is there an easy way to create a NSInvocation from the parameter list or do I have to check every element for it's type and add it accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're adding a method to the class, why not add/swizzle `forwardInvocation:` instead? At that point the runtime will have nicely built an invocation for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. A simple google search  shows this article:

http://www.wincent.com/a/about/wincent/weblog/archives/2006/03/nsinvocation_an.php

Which clearly explains how `va_args` don't properly work with NSInvocation.

Comment: ok, but then how does a call to the `forwardInvocation:` method work internally? Because as I understand it a call to this method has to do this.

Comment: I don't see `-forwardInvocation:` being called anywhere, no matter what the selector I pass to NSArray... and from the docs, 

`The message that’s forwarded must have a fixed number of arguments; variable numbers of arguments (in the style of printf()) are not supported.`

Comment: I don't want to invoke a method with a arg list, I just like to use a va_args list to call a method with a fix number of args. But it looks like i have to deal with all the `NSMethodSignature getArgumentTypeAtIndex:` stuff to get this working.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible, indeed. Have a look to the actionSelectorImplementation function in https://github.com/rlopezdiez/TMInstanceMethodSwizzler/blob/master/Classes/TMInstanceMethodSwizzler.m